# How do I get translated paragraph values?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

```
{% for item in contents.hotel_attractions.field_banner_image_slider %}
    <h1>{{item.entity.field_main_caption.value}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

`field_banner_image_slider` is a paragraph entity. `field_main_caption` is a field of the paragraph.

I have used `$node->getTranslation($language)` to get the translated node. In twig with the above code it prints the default language value without translation. In the same node the contents which are not from a paragraph entity prints the translated value correctly.

I have enabled the translations for paragraph fields from configurations.

Comment: You can get the translated paragraph in preprocess the same way you get the translated node. But normally you don't need so much code to render a paragraph field, if you theme it in a paragraph template.

Comment: @4k4 I didn't get what you said. Could you please elaborate more :)

Comment: If you want to access the paragraph directly, then use `$paragraph->getTranslation($language)` in preprocess, like you already do for the node. But as said, better let the paragraph render itself and use another template (you see this in the Twig Debug output).